# Jquery Find every all cells with a certain text and delete entire row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I am trying to do some work with tables and jQuery. Basically, I want to be able to go through an entire column based on its header and look for certain values. If those values are present I want to then delete the entire row. My code so far can select the correct column:

```
ownerIndex = $('th:contains("Outstanding")').index();
$('table tr td:nth-child('+ownerIndex+')').parent().hide();
```

From here I am unsure how to do an 'if' statement to look at the  values. I am looking for all cells with the value of "0.00".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what kind of value you  want to look for specify that clearly

Answer (score 0):

Loop through each td element you selected using jQuery *each* function:

```
$('table tr td:nth-child('+ownerIndex+')').each( function(){
   if($(this).html() == "0.00") {
     // do your stuff
   }
});
```